# How to get referenced automatically 'Accessibility(System32\oleacc.dll)' by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, guid

May I ask how to get to know right GUID of 'Accessibility(System32\oleacc.dll)' for every Access version?

I'd like to get VBA library for 'Accessibility(System32\oleacc.dll)' automatically, depends on the client Access version, using like script as follows.

< Set Excel library depends on Client Access Version >

```
Sub Set_RefExcel()

On Error GoTo Err_Set_RefExcel

 Dim Ref As Reference
 Dim AccVer As String
 Dim strExcel As String

 'Once Unset Any Excel Reference
 Call Unset_RefExcel

 'Check Access Vertion
 AccVer = GetAccessVersion 'Get Access Version my Formular

 Select Case AccVer
    Case "16.0"
        strExcel = "{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"      
    Case "15.0" 'Access2013
        strExcel = "{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    Case "14.0" 'Access2010
        strExcel = "{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
    Case Else
 End Select

 'Set Reference
 Set Ref = References.AddFromGuid(strExcel, 1, 3)
 Set Ref = Nothing

 Exit Sub

Err_Set_RefExcel:
 If Err.Number = 32813 Then
 Resume Next
 Else
    MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
 End If
```

The reason why I'd like to this is, would like to compact and repair database by VBA, when detect the mdb file getting close to its limit size, 2GB. We need oleacc.dll to use Quick Access ToolBars like following script sample.

http://www.ka-net.org/office/of06.html#CompactAndRepairDatabase
(sorry, it's in all Japanese)

Any advice would be so helpful.

Regards,

Comment: `Ref.Guid` should get you the GUID of the reference. Can you play with that?

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt advice, @Foxfire And Burns And Burns.
Using Ref.Guid at my place, I can get it of my own Access, 15.0.

Debug.Print "Name: ", ref.Name, ref.Guid
Accessibility {1EA4DBF0-3C3B-11CF-810C-00AA00389B71}

Just wondering how to get them for other version.
If you have any further advice, would be so grateful.
Sincerly

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the GUID to add the reference if it has a fixed location on disk independent of the version.

Since it's always in a fixed path from your Windows directory, you can use that:

```
References.AddFromFile Environ("WINDIR") & "\System32\oleacc.dll"
```

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate your wonderful advice, @Erik von Asmuth !!
It's more better and quick solution, than my plan.
I'm sure to revise my current script according to your advice.
And check the current libraly, using Ref.Guid  Foxfire And Burns And Burns kindly let me know. (If it already has been refered, skip to add it).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of usuful advice, revised my script.
Now we can automatically make it compact and repair, when would expand.

Just FYI:

-- Script for Set Accessibility Reference.

```
Sub Set_AccessibilityReference()

Dim Ref As Reference

'To Avoid 32183 Error, Once Remove Accessibility Reference if already referred
For Each Ref In References
If Ref.Name = "Accessibility" Then
Application.References.Remove Ref
End If
Next Ref

'Accessibility Reference Add
References.AddFromFile Environ("WINDIR") & "\System32\oleacc.dll"

End Sub
```

-- Set reference before call procedure for Compact and Repair Database

```
Sub Chk_Optimization(ByVal ChkSizeByte As Long)

On Error Resume Next

Dim strFileName As String
Dim CurrentSizeByte As Long

'Set Reference
Set_AccessibilityReference

'Get Current File Size
strFileName = Application.CurrentDb.Name
CurrentSizeByte = FileLen(strFileName)

'File Size Check
If CurrentSizeByte > ChkSizeByte Then
'Call Procedure for Auto Compact And Repair Database
Exec_CompactAndRepairDatabase
End If

End Sub
```

-- Before extract and export reports, if file exceeds 0.5 GB, then Compact and Repair

```
Chk_NeedOptimization 536870912
```

Again, I really appreciate Erik von Asmuth and Foxfire And Burns And Burns.

Further advice would be grateful.
If anyone notice any issue, please let me know.

Best Regards,